# Difficulty making 2 subplots in a figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I've been trying to solve this issue for a while but I got stuck. Can anyone point out what is wrong in this code snippet?

[image: This is a stacked histogram]

I am trying to add in titles, labels and legend but it seems to not apply to the histogram I want.

Here is the error:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `ax1 = plt.hist(...)`, do `ax1.hist(...)`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks soo much